# Generar JSON de forma dinámica desde JAVA

Tags: java, javascript, json, datetime

Estoy tratando de generar un gráfico utilzando `chart.js` y el plugin `Scatter.js`

Estoy teniendo problemas para generar el `JSON` que genera el Gráfico.

Lo que necesito es:

```
var data3 = [
            {
                label: 'temperature',
                strokeColor: '#A31515',
                data: [
                    {
                        x: new Date('2011-04-11T11:45:00'),
                        y: 25
                    },
                    {
                        x: new Date('2011-04-11T12:51:00'),
                        y: 28
                    }
                ]
            }];
```

Estoy utilizando:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("x", new Date(date));
            obj.put("y", Integer.valueOf(magnitud));
            listDentro.add(obj);
```

Y obtengo:

```
var data3 = [
            {
                label: 'temperature',
                strokeColor: '#A31515',
                data: [
                        {'x':'2016-07-06T19:37:23.361-03:00','y':120},
                        {'x':'2016-07-06T15:57:45.762-03:00','y':120}]
            }];
```

Veo que el problema es que al utilizar `obj.put("x", new Date(date));` se crea el objeto `Date` y se retorna el `toString()`.

No he podido lograr `x: new Date(stringFecha)`.

Answer (score 1):

El formato JSON no tiene un tipo de dato de fecha. Este solo reconoce (http://json.org/):

- string (`'texto'`)
- number (`1234`)
- object (`{ propiedad: <valor> }`)
- array (`[<valor1>, <valor2>, <valor3>]`)
- `true`
- `false`
- `null`

donde `<valor>` es cualquiera de estás categorias.

Al no existir un estandar para fecha lo que la clase `JSONObject` hace es transformar las fechas de Java en un *string* con un formato estándar.

Ahora tú necesitas reconstruir este *string* de JSON en un objeto de JavaScript en el cliente, para esto puedes usar el segundo parámetro de `JSON.parse` que acepta una función para convertir los valores recibidos:

```
function dateParser(key, value) {
    if (!typeof value === 'string') {
        return value;
    }

    var isDate = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*))(?:Z|(\+|-)([\d|:]*))?$/;

    return isDate.test(value) ? new Date(value) : value;
}

var obj = JSON.parse(str, dateParser);
```

La función `dateParser` será invocada por cada propiedad del objeto, con esto puedes revisar si el valor es una fecha y en ese caso convertirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Menos elegante pero directo al valor que necesitas evaluar considerando que la data es para un gráfico donde podrías tener muchos elementos en el arreglo y evaluar cada propiedad de cada objeto puede mermar el tiempo de ejecución y memoria

```
function isDate(dateString){
var regexDate = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;
return regexDate.test(dateString) ? new Date(dateString) : dateString;
  }
for(i=0;i<data3.length;i++)
  for(j=0;j<data3[i].data.length;j++)
    data3[i].data[j].x = isDate(data3[i].data[j].x);
```